# Redirect some part of a website with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

I have a website where I want some secured parts.
Like example:

http://www.example.com/admin
http://www.example.com/webshop

I can redirect them to https

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^admin$ https://www.example.com/admin [L,R=301]
```

Except, It has multiple variables with it.

Like example: http://www.example.com/admin/page5/edit or http://www.example.com/webshop/product5/detail

I want every page that starts with /admin or /webshop redirected to https.
I tried with $1 $2 but couldn't solve it, because its not always the same amount of variables..

How can I manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add a condition that checks the entire directory in Apache like this. Do the same with your /webshop URIs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/.\*
RewriteRule ^(.\*)$ https://example.com$1 [R,L]
```